# What I can do if my questions limit had been reached in MO from long time?

Tags: support, math-stackexchange, closed-questions, post-ban

Really, I'm interested in posting new questions in MathOverflow such that I have some unanswered questions in S.E which I want to post them in MO, but my questions limit had been reached for some reason then I can't really now to post any question.

**Here my question is:**

What I can do to post questions if my questions limit  had been  reached in MO from long time?

Comment: What do you mean by *question limit*? Do you actually mean [question ban](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans). That is, do you get this message when posting question: "We are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the [Help Center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans) to learn more."?

Comment: yes i have got the second "We are no longer accepting questions from this account"

Comment: Have you followed the links Martin gave you?

Comment: Looking at zeraoulia's [list of questions](https://mathoverflow.net/users/51189/zeraoulia-rafik?tab=questions), I can't see any reason why a question ban would be warranted.  There isn't an excessive number of questions, nor an excessive rate.  The most recent question is from last February.  There are a few older questions with negative scores, but most have positive scores, and a few were very popular.  Unless there were a lot of negative questions that have been deleted, I would wonder if this ban is correct - is there a way to ask a moderator to review it?

Comment: @NateEldredge: I seem to recall that there were some recent questions that were heavily downvoted and deleted (though I could be mistaking the OP for someone else -- there have been a lot of bad questions recently).  But I don't know how to find links to them if I am correct.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I do not know whether there is some reasonable advice apart from what you can already read in the [help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans) and this FAQ post: [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997). Usually the way out of question ban is rather difficult. Maybe some experienced MO user would be willing to look at your past questions and possibly suggest some improvements.

Comment: I will also add that the title of your question is not ideal, since question limit usually refers to [50q/month, 6q/day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-questions-i-can-ask) limit which is enabled on *some* sites. (AFAIK not here on MO.) So now that you have seen help and faq, you might be able to rephrase the question using a more usual terminology.

Comment: @NateEldredge Based on deleted questions with negative scores in the past year, the ban does not seem surprising.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, Does answers for other questions in MO with positive scores help me to open my account in the side of posting questions ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik No, I don't think so. There is a blocking mechanism for answers as well, and the two are separated.

Comment: I believe I have heard claims that answers can help, but the contribution is very minor. The [official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) formulate this only very carefully: "If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for sure." (But I agree with @ToddTrimble that you probably should not put too much hopes in help from upvoted answers.)

Answer (score 3):

In a similar question from 2014 on a sister site, Stack Overflow, [What should an user do when he's in a question ban with unsalvageable questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280870), a moderator answered:

> The typical recourse for a user in a situation like this is to contact the [SO] team for assistance. When contacting the team, you need to show that you have understood how the site works and are capable of learning from your mistakes and asking better questions. What happens with your account depends on the situation, but usually this can mean either disassociating the absolute worst questions from your account so they no longer contribute to the ban, or if your account is really unsalvageable, they might remove it altogether so you can create a new one. . . .

In a recent duplicate question, [As a question-banned user on Stack Overflow should I delete my bad questions or edit them to ask some other question in their place?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362314), one commentator asked ([link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362314/as-a-question-banned-user-on-stack-overflow-should-i-delete-my-bad-questions-or#comment550747_362314)):

> I'm a bit surprised by the advice . . . from a moderator. Is that guidance still appropriate today?

and a community manager for the Stack Exchange Network responded  ([link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362314/as-a-question-banned-user-on-stack-overflow-should-i-delete-my-bad-questions-or?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment550777_362314)):

> With the rare exception, . . . we don't really do anything with them beyond send[ing] a canned response . . .

So this may offer a faint hope in rare exceptional circumstances, at least on SO.