# Why MO community forbide me and discourage me to do my research and to post my questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban, account-suspension

I'm confused why MO community forbids me many times to ask question however the last question that I have posted wasn't negative , Really  this method of dealing is discouraging me and discourage all OP there who they are interesting to do research, Now my question is: What I should do for continuation of posting question without creating a new account? and thanks

Comment: Which is your last question? Is there a link to it?

Comment: In case you don't know, there is StackExchange software that automatically blocks questions or answers if there is repeated downvoting/closure/deletion of posts. So the community doesn't directly block you, but how your posts are received does enter into it. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th.

Comment: Could you please write in your question a bit clearly in what way you are discouraged from posting questions? Are you talking about your question being put on hold? Are you getting the message “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account” as mentioned by Todd Trimble? (If it is the latter, the questions, the question should be probably tagged (post-ban) rather than (account-suspension) - and you can find links to some basic information [in the tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/post-ban/info).)

Comment: Based on comment you wrote under your previous question, it seems that you are talking about question ban: [What I can do if my questions limit had been reached in MO from long time?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3584) According to [the help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans): "If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated."

Comment: @Yemon, there seem to be several accounts in the name of OP, but perhaps https://mathoverflow.net/users/51189/zeraoulia-rafik is relevant. There you can see many questions that have been posted (but if there are any deleted questions, I don't think they show up there).

Comment: @YemonChoi , This is the link of the last question :https://mathoverflow.net/q/301696/51189

Comment: So, let's have a look: you have 21 questions (not counting possible deleted ones) with median score 2, and of those questions 9 are closed and 3 have negative score. Unless I am mistaken, deleted questions count towards a question ban as well (though details are not publicly available). In order to get the software-side ban lifted, you might try to improve your deleted questions to get them undeleted (or undelete them yourself, in case you have deleted them yourself), and to improve your closed questions to get them reopened and upvoted. -- I hope this is of some help!

Answer (score 7):

It's quite difficult to give an answer to your question. (At least to the part about reinstating the question ban after a positively received question.)

One thing is that the algorithm for determining question ban is not public. But you also omitted quite a lot of details in your question: What exactly was the the error message you get? At the time of the meta post, were you actually [banned from asking questions](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans) or just [limited to one question per week](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-limited)? Since you most recent question - which you mention as being positively received - have you posted some other questions that were deleted? So from the data available to other users it is difficult to find out whether the situation is indeed as described in your post - that some kind of ban kicked in after a positively received question. (The most recent question from this account that I see has score 2 with three upvotes and one downvote, all of these four votes have been cast [before this question on meta](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/301696/timeline).)

However, since you have explicitly mentioned creating a second account to solve the problem, let me address at least this. (And add a few words about question ban in general.)

### Multiple accounts

You wrote (emphasis mine): "What I should do for continuation of posting question **without creating a new account**?"

Creating another account just to bypass the question ban is not the way to go. This is **against the rules** - and depending on how strict moderators are, this could even lead to suspension.

Similarly as with many other topics, you can find some basic info about using multiple accounts [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/multiple-accounts/info). Briefly summarized, multiple accounts are allowed, but they should not interact with each other and you should not do things you are not able to do with a single account.

[Network-wide FAQ on multiple accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) explicitly says that they should not be usd for: "Circumventing suspensions, quality bans, or the rate limits on posting questions / answers / comments / etc." Similarly [the FAQ on post ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) says: "Can I simply create a new account? No. The automatic ban is at a lower level than account."

### General advice for question ban

From what I have heard on several meta sites, it seems that it is quite difficult to get from question ban. There aren't many things to say which aren't already covered by the help center and FAQ [on the question bans](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/post-ban/info) - so probably the best advice is to read and follow the recommendations given there.

Still, perhaps a few minor points:

- If your questions were received in a way which was sufficient to trigger question ban, maybe it can be considered as a signal from the community on this site that they are not the type of the questions this site welcomes. Maybe you could consider whether your questions would be more suitable elsewhere. There is [Mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions) in the Stack Exchange network [many other websites](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3760) on the Internet.
- It can happen that your ban is lifted even without you doing anything - simply if enough users randomly stumble upon your post and upvote them. Here is an example from another site where this happened: [I have been banned from asking questions, what should I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24782#24784). (It is natural that your post on meta might attract some attention to your post on main. However, when I look at the reputation tab in your profile, it seems that they lead to downvotes rather than upvotes.)
- I will repeat that according to [the help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans): "If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated." So maybe a reasonable strategy would be simply to wait for 6 months. (And prepare a question about which you are confident that it is on-topic for the site and is going to be well received.)
- Both help center and FAQ mention editing your old question as a possibility to help. I will just add some caveat to be careful with this - and do it only if you are confident that you can get them into the shape suitable for MathOverflow. (Otherwise these action might have opposite effect - bumping the question might bring new attention to them and if MO users do not consider them of sufficient quality you will receive several new downvotes and you'll just dig yourself deeper into the question ban.)
- Take seriously [warnings displayed by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118). If from a warning (on from your past experience) you suspect that you might be close to to triggering question ban, before posting the next question it might be useful to reread: [How to write a good MathOverflow question?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/882)